# Is it possible to keyframe the camera by hand instead of motion tracking?

Tags: animation, objects, tracking

I’ve been trying to track a complicated clip for a few days already but just can’t get it to track properly. Would it be possible to set the clip as the background and keyframe the camera by hand? Someone who has done that before? Not sure what to do otherwise

Comment: I think there is only one way to find out, you have to try it yourself. Chances are, if it is really complicated, that you will not succeed. But then again, you might as well be lucky. If you are reasonably sure about your camera's FOV and the size of key objects in your scene, your chances are at least realistic...

Comment: Just to clarify, you can keyframe the camera object’s location rotation and scale just like any other object. When I want to set a clip as a background, I usually input it as a texture in the world background and use “window“ coordinates to get it in place.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's worth a try. I Hope it will work!